# Is it possible to create a new Azure Search Service with Azure Search SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am writing a admin back end to manage our Azure search stuff and I was wondering if there is a way to use Azure Search SDK to create a new Azure Search Service on Azure portal? I don't see anything in the examples on the official Azure search site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to programmatically create Azure Search services in a few different ways:

1. Azure Search Management SDK

   - [.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/?term=microsoft.azure.management.search)
   - [.NET (fluent)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Search.Fluent/)
   - [Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/?view=azure-python&term=search)
   - [Ruby](https://rubygems.org/gems/azure_mgmt_search)
   - [Java (fluent)](https://learn.microsoft.com/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.search?view=azure-java-stable)
   - [Go](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/tree/master/services/search/mgmt/2015-08-19/search)
2. [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/azurerm.search/)
3. [Management REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchmanagement/)
4. [Azure Resource Manager Templates (example)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-azure-search-create/azuredeploy.json)

Documentation coverage for these is somewhat patchy currently. There are samples for the [REST API](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/search-dotnet-management-api/tree/master/src) and [.NET Fluent SDK](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/search-dotnet-manage-search-service) and reference documentation for some of the above.

Comment: There is a Java sample project too https://github.com/Azure-Samples/search-java-manage-search-service

Comment: Thanks. I added the Java SDK to the list.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use Azure Search SDK to create a new Search Service. This SDK is to manage data in an existing Search Service.

To create a Search Service programmatically, you will need to use `Azure Search Management` library. You can read more about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/search?view=azure-dotnet#management-library.

Comment: The .NET Management SDK isn't the only way. I've listed all of them in my answer.

Comment: @BruceJohnston Agreed. I only mentioned Management SDK because the question was about using Search .Net SDK to create (provision) a new Service. In any case, your answer is definitely more comprehensive.